# mysqli_fetch loop not working

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I have a loop inside other loop which is not working, this is the code:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['rowId'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['startDate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['eventName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['betName'] . "</td>";
    $string1 = "SELECT * FROM newCell WHERE rowId ='";
    $string2 = $row['rowId']."'";
    $result2 = $string1.$string2;
    echo "<td>" . $result2 . "</td>";

    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        echo "<td>" . $row2['odds'] . "</td>";

        echo "<td>" . $row2['outcomeName'] . "</td>";
    }
   echo "</tr>";
   }
```

When I query $result2 directly into the BBDD for the first result it shows three results but the code doesn't go in the second LOOP. Why? Any error here?

Comment: You aren't executing the query for second loop anywhere.

Comment: show us your both query..

Comment: You're asking it to loop through a `string`, not an `mysqli` object?

Comment: Where is your Query execution in $string1

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` works on query result not on query string

Comment: `result2 = mysqli_query($string1.$string2);`

Comment: @superTramp What's wrong in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['rowId'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['startDate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['eventName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['betName'] . "</td>";
    $string1 = "SELECT * FROM newCell WHERE rowId ='";
    $string2 = $row['rowId']."'";
    $result2 = $string1.$string2;
    echo "<td>" . $result2 . "</td>";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $result2);

    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        echo "<td>" . $row2['odds'] . "</td>";

        echo "<td>" . $row2['outcomeName'] . "</td>";
    }
   echo "</tr>";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$query = "SELECT ....";
$result2 = mysqli_query($db, $query);

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
        echo "<td>" . $row2['odds'] . "</td>";

        echo "<td>" . $row2['outcomeName'] . "</td>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think $result2 should be output of `mysqli_query` not just merely query. Talking in analogous to MySQL.

Probably you should have something like this

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before read this [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/12822319#12822319) topic. After try to use [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['rowId'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['startDate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['eventName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['betName'] . "</td>";
    $string1 = "SELECT * FROM newCell WHERE rowId ='";
    $string2 = $row['rowId']."'";
    $result2 = $string1.$string2;
    echo "<td>" . $result2 . "</td>";
    $results = mysqli_query($db,$result2);
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        echo "<td>" . $row2['odds'] . "</td>";

        echo "<td>" . $row['outcomeName'] . "</td>";
    }
   echo "</tr>";
   }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before fetching data execute mysql query using mysqli_query() function then run mysqli_fetch_array(). It would be good if you count result as $count = mysqli_num_rows($query) and manage your code with if... else .